# Symfony event listener that can check my database

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I want to build a custom event listener but I have trouble with the symfony documentation to understand what do I need to do to make a listener. Is that possible to create a listener that react when a timer go off ?
I want to start this timer in a controller, then popup an alert() when it goes off.

I saw this documentatino on Stopwatch : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html .I guess I should use that, but when I do `$stopwatch->start('foo');` in my controller, but how do I make my foo listener to do something when 10 minutes has passed ? How can I stop my timer in another controller ? Is there really a way to do that? I am really confused, I don't understand the documentation.
Thank for your help.

Comment: "_The Stopwatch component provides a way to profile code._" - you are not profiling code, so the stopwatch component is not right for this. I think this is quite a complex topic and you haven't really researched it yet .. How I would do it: Create db entry with datetime when timer ends, check this value in regular intervals (via AJAX, websocket, cron) and do the appropriate action once the timer ended

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm not gonna bother with listener, I will use `window.setInterval` and check my database every 5 secondes with ajax